# C++ menu sfml center all things

Tags: c++, menu, window, center, sfml

```
enter code sf::FloatRect textRect = text.getLocalBounds();
//Font
if(!font.loadFromFile("arial.ttf")){}

//Tło - trzeba załadować
if(!texture.loadFromFile("bg_menu.png")){}

//play
mainMenu[0].setFont(font);
mainMenu[0].setFillColor(sf::Color::Blue);
mainMenu[0].setString("Play");
mainMenu[0].setCharacterSize(40);
mainMenu[0].setPosition(sf::Vector2f(width / 2, hight / (Max_main_menu + 1)));
//center text (?)
mainMenu[0].setOrigin(textRect.left + textRect.width / 2.0f,
    textRect.top + textRect.height / 2.0f);
mainMenu[1].setOrigin(textRect.left + textRect.width / 2.0f,
    textRect.top + textRect.height / 2.0f);
mainMenu[2].setOrigin(textRect.left + textRect.width / 2.0f,
    textRect.top + textRect.height / 2.0f);
```

Main menu :

```
enter main(){
RenderWindow window(VideoMode(SCREEN_HIGH, SCREEN_WIDTH), "Age of Ants!", Style::Close);
Main_menu menu(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HIGH);
while (window.isOpen()) {
    sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            window.close();
        //Movin in Menu - Up&Down&Selecting start
        if (event.type == Event::KeyReleased) {
            if (event.key.code == Keyboard::Up) {
                menu.moveUP();
                break;
            }
            if (event.key.code == Keyboard::Down) {
                menu.moveDOWN();
                break;
            }
            if (event.key.code == Keyboard::Return) {
                switch (menu.mainMenuPressed()) {
                case 0:
                    cout << "Play button has been pressed" << endl;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    cout << "Options button has been pressed" << endl;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    window.close();
                    cout << "Exit button has been pressed" << endl; 
                    break;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOGwI.png)

I do not know how to center this menu,  I would like to bo center (on the middle) and looks like on the image I have attached. [][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uqq3v.png) Seconde image is the menu right now - how it looks like...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to center any image or text then

```
sf::Vector2f position;
position.x = ((windowSize.x - imageSize.x) / 2.0f);
position.y = ((windowSize.y - imageSize.y) / 2.0f);
```

This works for images whose origin to the topleft of the image